# How can you plot a tangent line and curve given the parametric equations for each?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

If a curve is defined by parametric equations $x=t, y=e^{-2t}, z=3t-t^3$

and the tangent line at point (0,1,0) is defined by $x=t, y=1-2t, z=3t$,

How would you determine which of the following graphs accurately represent this scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints.

The first and fourth figure show a curve that is bounded in at least two dimensions.  Is you curve bounded in any dimension?

In the third, you can see that the curve is quite linear with $x$ or $y$ hanging around $2$.  Does your curve do that?  Is your curve linear?

The second figure is very poor, but if you can eliminate the other choices, what is left?